# NRow of predicted data is not true

Tags: r

I am trying to ask for predicting a feature from 16000 observation. Here is the train data. Here is the train part:

```
res<-lm(target~usage2+usage5+usage1+usage4+usage3+days+agegroup,data=train)
```

`nrow(train)` gives me **16000**

and when i ask for prediction with **test dataset**

```
predictedData<-predict(res,data=test)
```

The  `nrow(test)` gives me **4000**

**Therefore, i expect the output of** `predict` also contains **4000**, but surprisingly, it has **16000**

```
NROW(predictedData)
[1] 16000
```

Comment: Try `predict(res, newdata=test)`. See `?predict.lm` for additional information.

Comment: It is `newdata` not `data`  ` predictedData<-predict(res,newdata=test)`